Kafkaconnect not able to find S3Sinkconnector
I have downloaded and added S3connector libs from confluent into folder
/usr/share/java/kafka/s3-connect
I can see all necessary jars under above location
Also added
/config/connect-standalone.properties

with
plugin.path=/usr/share/java/kafka/s3-connect

But when I run this command
curl -i -X PUT -H "Accept:application/json" \
    -H  "Content-Type:application/json" http://localhost:8083/connectors/sink/config \
    -d '
 {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector",
        "key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "topics": "cats",
        "s3.region": "eu-west-1",
        "s3.bucket.name": "snowplow-kafka-s3-sink-test",
        "flush.size": "65536",
        "storage.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage",
        "format.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.format.avro.AvroFormat",
        "schema.generator.class": "io.confluent.connect.storage.hive.schema.DefaultSchemaGenerator",
        "schema.compatibility": "NONE",
        "partitioner.class": "io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.DefaultPartitioner",
        "transforms": "AddMetadata",
        "transforms.AddMetadata.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField$Value",
        "transforms.AddMetadata.offset.field": "_offset",
        "transforms.AddMetadata.partition.field": "_partition"
    }
'

I get error

HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
{"error_code":500, "message": "Failed to find any class that implements connector and which name matches io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector"}

tried moving jars into /opt/kafka/libs ,,, and kept all possible directories in class path
Still no luck
I can see when pod starts it's loading all the plugins
loading plugin from : /usr/share/java/kafka/s3-connect (org.apache.kafka.connect.Runtime.isolation.PluginScanner:75)
Registered laoder: PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:/usr/share/java/kafka/s3-connect}

WARN one or more plugins are missing ServiceLoader manifests may not be usable with pligin.discovery=service_load: [
file:/usr/share/java/kafka/avro/ io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter converter undefined
file:/usr/share/java/kafka/s3-connect/ io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector sink 10.5.9
file:/usr/share/java/kafka/s3-connect/ io.confluent.connect.storage.tools.SchemaSourceConnector source 3.6.0
.
.
.
down the lane
INFO Added plugin ‘io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector’
.
.
.
INFO Added alias ‘S3SinkConnector’ to plugin ‘io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector’


Then further in  logs I can see reading s3.properties when creating connector
and gets Finished starting connectors and tasks
then i see
ERROR error forwarding REST request
org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.test.errors.ConnectRestException: Failed to find any class that implements Connector and which name matches io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector


the following command shows plugin is available
curl http://localhost:8083/connector-plugins/

[{“class”:“io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector”, “type”:“sink”,“version”:“10.5.9”} – and other plugins


what is problem,
I have downloaded zip files from confluent and unzipped into location /usr/share/java/kafka/s3-connect
And I use amazoncorretto-apline17 image
as confluent image I can't attach IAM role.
someone help me.
